# The visual human test sometimes appears very far away from the captcha checkbox in SEDE

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha, iphone, mobile-chrome

The visual human test sometimes appears very far away from the captcha checkbox:

> [image: IMG:]
> <sub>*(click for full size)*</sub>

Tested on an iPhone with Chrome. This is inconvenient because one has to unzoom to find it. It’s easy to miss if one doesn’t think of unzooming:

> [image: IMG:]
> <sub>*(click for full size)*</sub>

Comment: We need a smaller screen ...

Comment: @rene We also need a better way to insert small images when using a phone. It’s a pain to add the proper HTML code to reduce the image size and I don’t want to lower the resolution. Do you have a solution?

Comment: There isn't any control at the SEDE site by the looks of it for where that challenge gets displayed. It looks like we're at the mercy of whatever Google returns for their iframe. Unless Tim Stone knows from the top of his head where this is controlled you might be out of luck. I don't like dealing with hacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569835

Comment: @rene thanks for the edit, I appreciate it, but please don't lower the resolution.

Comment: Well SEDE is not really responsive,  and doubt there's anyone who is willing to make it responsive, it's not something SE is responsible for. They're responsible to keep it going and keep the data flowing, but design is something private people are doing.

Comment: (rolled back since [What issues does using the HTML width attribute for images create?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393836/178179) received no answers)