# What issues does using the HTML width attribute for images create?

Tags: support, images, html-entities

I [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/393776/5):

> Using the HTML width attribute is known to cause issues when using some layout modifiers - I used to use it too but got complaints. [Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog)

What issues does using the HTML width attribute for images create?

Comment: IIRC it was ArtOfCode who rolled back my edits to add this exact thing at the time. Now that I think of it, it may have had to do with deprecated mobile things.

Comment: Curious as well. The width and height attributes should, if anything, be _encouraged_ as much as possible because they prevent page jumping. When the attributes are directly defined, the browser reserves that amount of space on the page for when they are loaded. If they are not, the browser reserves no space and causes the page to jump around as images load and it's able to determine how much space they need.